# cakephp join for selectbox

Tags: mysql, join, cakephp-3.0

Thats a question for **cakephp 3.0**

I have three tables on mysql:

```
--------------
Users
--------------
id
name
lastname
phone
rol_id

--------------
Rols
--------------
id
name

--------------
Doctors
--------------
id
user_id
speciality
```

I want get doctors name and id who rol is 3 (for example)

the query to do this is:

```
SELECT users.name, doctors.id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN doctors ON doctors.userid = users.id
WHERE users.rol_id = 3
```

That i need is pass this query to cakephp for display a selectbox
the selectbox's value is user.name and the key is doctors.id

Someone can help me.

Really thnx!

**Update after harpax comment:**

I'm in patients controller, in patients view add, patient must chose a doctor, so i need to show them all.
The doctor id is in doctor table
The doctor name is in user table
The doctors can be doctors or nurse (I only need doctors)
This is defined by the role of a user, doctor, nurse or patient

**My query in controller**

```
$doctors = $this->Patients->Doctors->find()
->select(['Users.user_name','Doctors.id'])
->where(['Users.rol_id' => '3'])
->contain('Users');
```

Pass to view the doctors var:

```
$this->set(compact('patient', 'users', 'countries', 'rols', 'doctors'));
```

**My add template**

```
echo $this->Form->input('patient.doctor_id', ['class' =>'css_input_field css_color_input css_background_color_input', 'label'=>false, 'options' => $doctors]);
```

**Expected result**

A Selectbox that on text show doctors name and doctors id in value.

**Result**

[Click here for view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMyn3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your UsersController

```
$doc = $this->Users->find()
    ->select(['Users.name', 'Doctors.id')
    ->where(['Users.role_id' => 3])
    ->contain(['Doctors'])
    ->first();
```

should generate the needed query

Comment: That is correct. Really thanks. But is incomplete. I need pass the result to a selectbox template. –

Update my questión for show it